# Avalonia DataGrid add row number by using styles

Tags: avaloniaui, avalonia

I have many DataGrid elements in my solution and I need to add row numbers there.
In Avalonia Github page they advices to use style.  [image]

Could you tell me please how to create such style and show rowNumbers in first DataGrid column.